# Multiple Delete Statements Inside of Cursor DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am attempting to delete from multiple tables within a cursor in a DB2 system. However the terminator character `;` is causing my cursor to exit prematurely. Currently I can not determine another way to set this query up to achieve the desired results.

I tried the below statement:

```
DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR
DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PARAM;
DELETE FROM TABLE2 WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PARAM;
DELETE FROM TABLE3 WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PARAM;
DELETE FROM TABLE4 WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PARAM;
DELETE FROM TABLE5 WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PARAM;
DELETE FROM TABLE6 WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PARAM;
DELETE FROM TABLE7 WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PARAM;
```

However this did not run as expected, meaning that it will not loop through a cursor, instead it just runs once.

This also fails to run:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PARAM@
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PARAM@
SELECT * FROM TABLE3 WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PARAM@
SELECT * FROM TABLE4 WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PARAM@
SELECT * FROM TABLE5 WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PARAM@
SELECT * FROM TABLE6 WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PARAM@
SELECT * FROM TABLE7 WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PARAM@;
OPEN C1@
```

Here I tried to change the cursor terminator character so that it would get further down and actually open and run the cursor, however this threw a an error and did not run at all.

How can I rewrite this statement to run multiple select statements within a cursor?

Comment: Can I do that within the stored procedure?

Comment: [you can try](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0053426.html)

Comment: So, [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.apsg/src/tpc/db2z_setsqlterminator.dita) isn't working at all? Just outside of cursor, without it?

Comment: Why do you think you need a cursor?  Nothing you've needs a cursor.

Comment: I kinda came to the same conclusion, working with an If, ElseIf, Then solution now

Comment: This looks like somebody forgot to put in foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.  In a situation like this I'd write a stored procedure (which you already have) and just issue multiple `DELETE` statements (probably one block per transaction).  Except for specific uses, cursors should be avoided in favor of set-based solutions.  Oh, and you can't use cursors for anything but `SELECT` statements anyways (you can issue `DELETE`/`UPDATE` on the current row with `FOR CURRENT OF`, if you've set the cursor up right, but it's a performance hog)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm much more used to T-SQL/MSSQL Server and I'm kinda feeling my way through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the OPEN C1 you need to loop through the results stored in the cursor.

with the

```
OPEN C1
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @Variable1,@Variable2,....( as many as fields in the table )
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @Variable1,@Variable2,....( as many as fields in the table )
END

CLOSE CURSOR
DEALLOCATE CURSOS
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you need a cursor to delete data?

It is far better to do this:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE colname = (SELECT colname FROM table1 WHERE condition);
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE colname = (SELECT colname FROM table2 WHERE condition);
DELETE FROM table3 WHERE colname = (SELECT colname FROM table3 WHERE condition);
DELETE FROM table4 WHERE colname = (SELECT colname FROM table4 WHERE condition);
```

There should be no problem running this in a stored procedure.

Comment: He doesn't even need the subselect in your example - just use the `WHERE` condition as part of the `DELETE`.  Also, note this fails if the subselect returns more than one row.